# Writing new HTML using JQuery disables popover

Tags: jquery, popover

I am using JQuery's sortable and the serialize in order to save the position to my database.
Position saved in database example: `["13","1","7","3","12","5","9","0","2","4","6","8","10","11"]`

And I have an UL tag and each list has an id like such: category-0, category-1, category-2 until 13.

So on page load, if the user is connected obviously, I am reordering the list like this:

```
    var categoriesPos = '#{data.user.CategoriesPos}'; 
    categoriesPos = JSON.parse(categoriesPos.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));

    var categList = document.querySelectorAll('ul')[4]
    var categLi = categList.getElementsByTagName("LI");

    var categoriesP = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        categoriesP.push(categLi[categoriesPos[i]])
    }

    $('.categories-sortable ul').html(categoriesP)
```

However, my problem is that every list has a "more .." button that triggers a popover on hover.
This line breaks the popover: `$('.categories-sortable ul').html(categoriesP)`

It works, it sorts correctly etc, as I said, the only issue is just that it breaks the popover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery  `prepend()` or `append()` for the whole sorted collection depending on where the more button is

```js
// add event listener to keepme before rest of list gets modified
// since the element never gets removed from DOM will work after sort is done
$('#keepme').click(()=>console.log('clicked'))

const order = ["1","2","3"]

const items = $('.item').sort((a, b) => order.indexOf(a.id) -  order.indexOf(b.id))

$('#list').prepend(items)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <div id="3" class="item">Three</div>
  <div id="1" class="item">One</div>
  <div id="2" class="item">Two</div>

  <div id="keepme">Keep me here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, that worked. of course I had to tweak it just a bit, but it worked, thank you !